# Tor started by root although configured as debian-tor

Tags: configuration, systemd, tor

Upon booting Ubuntu 18 tor does not start correctly and gives the error message

```
 [warn] /var/lib/tor is not owned by this user (root, 0) but by debian-tor (122). Perhaps you are running Tor as the wrong user?
```

in the syslog. I have specified
`User=debian-tor`
in both

```
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/tor.service
```

and

```
/etc/systemd/system/tor.service.d/override.conf
```

but this does not help. I cannot find any more configuration files that specify the user. Can the problem come from the fact that I also have the Tor browser installed?

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe it's an interference with the browser.

I have just installed Tor on my raspberry pi with the latest software and I am experiencing the same problem.

I believe there is a bug somewhere...
P.S. I have "Tor version 0.2.9.15 (git-2dc1a1a2abab5403)"

Answer (score -1):

I think I have it working:
I changed the permissions to the folder `chmod 02700 sshd` to have it like this:

```
root@raspberrypi:/var/lib/tor# ls -lai
...
129841 drwx--S---  2 debian-tor debian-tor    4096 Oct 24 18:28 sshd
```

and I added in the file "/lib/systemd/system/tor.service" the string "User=debian-tor" as you did.

I disabled and re-enabled the service (sudo update-rc.d tor disable/enable) and it now seem to work

P.S. it always starts-up as root, then after a couple of minutes it changes user.

Comment: That is a very nasty hack with the set group id.